# Record Flattening in SQL

Tags: sql

I've been trying to find the answer to this without success. This may be because I don't know the right term to search for.

I've looked at some flattening suggestions using Pivot or Cross Apply but none of the examples I've looked at seem to do exactly what I want.

I basically need the most efficient way to flatten records in a table (because it's over a table with millions of records).

(Please excuse the formatting, I wasn't sure of the best way to make it readable).

Here's an example of what the original records look like :-

```
MainId--ID1--ID2--ID3
20241--0--2881--0
20241--0--2871--0
20241--0--2884--0
20241--1580--0--0
20241--1588--0--0
20241--0--0--1205
20241--0--0--1001
20241--0--0--1268
20241--0--0--1311
```

And here is what I need them to end up like :-

```
MainId--ID1--ID2--ID3
20241--1580--2881--1205
20241--1588--2871--1001
20241--0--2884--1268
20241--0--0--1311
```

So, I just need them to be the fewest number of records for each MainId.

It actually doesn't matter which ID's are in which record as there is no relation between them. They just need to be related to the correct MainId.

NB. This is a simplified example. The table in question can actually have up to 10 different ID columns but if I get it working for 3 ID's, I should be able to extend this out to more.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jason

Comment: what flavor of sql are you using and please post a query you've tried

Comment: Please confirm you don't have `-` characters in your table?  If so, please delete them from the question?  *(When formatted as code, SO uses fixed width characters, so they're not needed, just confusing.)*

Comment: Your results seem to assume an ordering in the table, but no column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  But you can do it using `union all` and aggregation.  However, you need a column that specifies the ordering if you care about the actual order in the results:

```
select main_id,
       max(id1), max(id2), max(id3)
from ((select t.*, row_number() over (partition by main_id order by ?) as seqnum
       from t
       where id1 <> 0
      ) union all
      (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by main_id order by ?) as seqnum
       from t
       where id2 <> 0
      ) union all
      (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by main_id order by ?) as seqnum
       from t
       where id3 <> 0
      )
     ) t
group by main_id, seqnum;
```

This enumerates the valid values for each column and then combines them on a single row.  The `?` is for the ordering column.  If you don't care about the ordering just use `main_id`.

Note:  This turns the `0`s into `NULL`s -- which seems useful to me.  You can use `coalesce()` if you really want them as `0`s.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, datasets / tables don't have an implicit order.  There isn't a "first" record, unless you can enforce an order using an `ORDER BY` clause.

This means that there's currently no way to determine that `2881` should be in the same row as `1580` *(`2881` could just as easily be put in the same row as `1588`.)*

To resolve this, I'm going to assume you actually have an additional column:

```
MainId    SubID    ID1    ID2    ID3
20241       1        0   2881      0
20241       2        0   2871      0
20241       3        0   2884      0
20241       1     1580      0      0
20241       2     1588      0      0
20241       1        0      0   1205
20241       2        0      0   1001
20241       3        0      0   1268
20241       4        0      0   1311
```

Then it's a matter of aggregating the rows together...

```
SELECT
  MainID,
  SubID,
  COALESCE(MAX(ID1), 0)   AS ID1,
  COALESCE(MAX(ID2), 0)   AS ID2,
  COALESCE(MAX(ID3), 0)   AS ID3
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  MainID,
  SubID
```